# Matching string in perl which is parsed with awk

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I did next with awk:

```
awk '/secon/ {print $1}' vladtest.sh |cut -c2-6
```

How to match this string in perl loop on appropriate way:

```
my $var1= `awk '/secon/ {print $1}' vladtest.sh |cut -c2-6`
if ($var1 eq "secon"){
    print "OK";
} else {
    print "FALSE"
}
```

Comment: Add "use sctrict;" and "use warnings;" in your perl script. Looks like you have not declared variable $var1 at all.

Comment: i did sorry just didnt copied well, i edited question

Comment: Then the "secon" can be just a part of the word. Use $var1 =~ /secon/ in Perl instead of eq.

Comment: Also, you not need to call AWK in Perl. You can do everything in Perl better.

Comment: Yes i know about that but i currently have not enough time to introduce with perregexp, do you have some good links about that ?

Comment: I love this one: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your problem is the fact that the result of `...` includes the newline.  So `$var1` is not `"secon"`, but `"secon\n"`.   You could deal with that any number of ways - wrapping `chomp(`...`)` around the whole assignment to `$var1`, or changing the right side of the `eq` to include the `"\n"`, or using a regex instead: `if ($var1 =~ /^secon$/)` works with or without the `chomp`, because `$` matches at a string-final newline if present.

Second of all, you're using about two programs too many here:

```
my $var1= `awk '/secon/ {print $1}' vladtest.sh |cut -c2-6`
```

I mean,`awk` can do anything `cut` can do, and `perl` can do anything either can do. When I'm typing one-liners at the shell prompt, I'm a big fan of `awk` and `cut`, simply for their economy of expression; within their respective specialities, their command lines are generally shorter than the equivalent (even using `perl -a` etc).  But since you're already in a Perl program, there's no reason to shell out to something else here.

Here's an example drop-in replacement for the above:

```
my $var1;
{ 
  open(my $fh, '<', 'vladtest.sh'); 
  while (<$fh>) { 
    $var1 .= substr(split(' ')[0],1,5)."\n" if /secon/;
  }
}
```

But you don't need to go through all that if you just want to detect if there's a match.

```
{open(my $fh, '<', 'vladtest.sh');
print 'NOT ' unless grep { /^\s*\Ssecon/ } <$fh>;
say 'OK';}  # or print "OK\n"; if you don't have 5.10 extensions enabled.
```

Comment: You can skip `open` and just use the _null file handle_ (aka Diamond operator). `print "NOT " grep { /^\s*\Ssecon/ } <>;` This will take the file offered on the command line or from STDIN (just like other Unix commands do).

Comment: sure, but that assumes that the file `vladtest.sh` is provided as a command-line argument to the Perl program, and that it's not using its command-line arguments for other things.

Answer (score 0):

My awk's a bit rusty, but you're grabbing $1 then looking for characters 2 through 6 to match 'secon'. If any line matches this, then print "OK", otherwise "NOT OK". Here's a perl only solution:

```
  use 5.10.0;

  while (<>) {
      if (/^\s*\Ssecon/) {
          say 'OK';
          exit 0;
      }
  }
  say 'NOT OK';
  exit 1;
```

The regexp is made up of:

```
  ^       match the start of each line, followed by
  \s*     zero or more whitespace characters, followed by
  \S      one non-whitespace character, followed by
  secon   the literal string that you're interested in
```

As soon as we have a line that matches, we can print 'OK' and exit. Otherwise we'll fall through the end of the loop and print 'NOT OK'.

The `use 5.10.0;` line is needed so you can use `say()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to implement this request, but follow your current idea , change the first line to resolve the issue.

```
my $var1= `awk '$1~/secon/ {print substr($1,2,5)}' vladtest.sh`
```

Comment: That replaces `cut` with an `awk` builtin, but doesn't resolve the issue -`$var1` is still `"secon\n"`, which does not `eq "secon"`.

Comment: this is perl script, then the requester should know how to remove the \n before compare it by chomp

Comment: but since that's the whole problem that they're asking about, they clearly don't.  we don't criticize questioners based on what they don't know.'